# On a real part of a series with complex numbers

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $P(z)=\sum_{m=0}^na_mz^m $ be a polynomial of degree $n$ having all its  zeros in $|z|\leq 1.$ Then what is the best value for 'L' in
$$\Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^nP(zw_k)\frac{w_k}{(w_k-1)^2}\right)\geq L$$ on $|z|=1$ where $w_k,\; 1\leq k\leq n$ are the $n$ roots of the polynomial $z^n+|a_0|=0?$

Comment: The value $|a_{0}|$ seems to be the constant term of the polynomial but its summation starts at $k=1$, so $|a_{0}|$ is undetermined. Can you say something about it ? Or should the summation in the definition of the polynomial $P(z)$ start at $k=0$ ?